# How to read csv file into an Array of arrays in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, csv, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to read a csv file and return it as an array of arrays of doubles (`Array[Array[Double]]`). It's pretty clear how to read in a file line by line and immediately print it out, but not how to store it in a two-dimensional array.

```
def readCSV() : Array[Array[Double]] = {
    val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/testData.csv")
    var matrix :Array[Array[Double]] = null
    for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
        val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
        matrix = matrix :+ cols
    }
    bufferedSource.close
    return matrix
}
```

Had some type issues and then realized I'm not doing what I thought I was doing. Any help pointing me on the right track would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your question was already answered. So just as a side note, you could write your code in a more scalaish way like this:

```
def readCSV() : Array[Array[Double]] = {
  io.Source.fromFile("/testData.csv")
    .getLines()
    .map(_.split(",").map(_.trim.toDouble))
    .toArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should start with an empty Array unstead of `null`. 
2) You append items to an Array with the operator `:+`
3) As your result type is `Array[Array[Double]]` you need to convert the strings of the csv to `Double`.

```
def readCSV() : Array[Array[Double]] = {
    val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/testData.csv")
    var matrix :Array[Array[Double]] = Array.empty
    for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
        val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim.toDouble)
        matrix = matrix :+ cols
    }
    bufferedSource.close
    return matrix
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Turns out this gets you the array of rows, not the array of columns, but it doesn't take much to turn that into the columns.