# CSV to Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, scala, csv, object, apache-spark

I am using a third party package for spark that utilizes a "PointFeature" object. I am trying to take a csv file and put elements form each row into an Array of these PointFeature objects.

The PointFeature constructor for my implementation looks like this:

```
Feature(Point( _c1, _c2), _c3)
```

where _c1, _c2, and _c3 are the columns of my csv and represent doubles.

Here is my current attempt:

```
val points: Array[PointFeature[Double]] = for{
    line <- sc.textFile("file.csv")
    point <- Feature(Point(line._c1,line._c2),line._c3)
} yield point
```

My error shows up when referencing the columns

```
<console>:36: error: value _c1 is not a member of String
   point <- Feature(Point(line._c1,line._c2),line._c3.toDouble)
                               ^
<console>:36: error: value _c2 is not a member of String
       point <- Feature(Point(line._c1,line._c2),line._c3.toDouble)
                                            ^
<console>:36: error: value _c3 is not a member of String
       point <- Feature(Point(line._c1,line._c2),line._c3.toDouble)
                                                      ^
```

This is obviously because I'm referencing a String as if it were an element of a DataFrame. I'm wondering if there is a way to work with DataFrames in this loop format, or a way to split each line into a List of doubles. Maybe I need an RDD?

Also, I'm not certain that this will yield an Array. Actually, I suspect it will return an RDD...

I am using Spark 2.1.0 on Amazon EMR

Here are some other Questions I have drawn from:

[How to read csv file into an Array of arrays in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055496/how-to-read-csv-file-into-an-array-of-arrays-in-scala)

[Splitting strings in Apache Spark using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820501/splitting-strings-in-apache-spark-using-scala)

[How to iterate records spark scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030726/how-to-iterate-records-spark-scala)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a `Dataset[Feature]` this way:

```
case class Feature(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double)
sparkSession.read.csv("file.csv")
    .toDF("x", "y", "z")
    .withColumn("x", 'x.cast(DoubleType))
    .withColumn("y", 'y.cast(DoubleType))
    .withColumn("z", 'z.cast(DoubleType))
    .as[Feature]
```

Then you can consume your strongly-typed `DataSet[Feature]` as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking this on in smaller steps.

**Step One**

Get your rows as an Array/List/whatever of Strings.

`val lines = sc.textFile("file.txt").getLines`, or something like that.

**Step Two**

Break your lines in to their own lists of columns.

`val splits = lines.map {l => l.split(",")}`

**Step Three**

Extract your colums as vals that you can use

```
val res = splits.map { 
  case Array(col1, col2, col3) => // Convert to doubles, put in to Feature/Point Structure}
  case _ => // Handle the case where your csv is malformatted
}
```

This can all be done in one go, I only split them to show the logical step from file → list string → list list string → list Feature